# Unable to use Kestrel with HTTPS with mutual handshaking (2 way SSL)

Tags: ssl, https, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

**Main method:**

```
 public static void InitHttpServer(ServerInitiatorParam sip)
    {   
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                     //.UseKestrel(options => { options.UseHttps(cert); })
                     .UseKestrel(options =>
                     {
                         var cert = new X509Certificate2("C:/cert/Test.pfx", "password");
                         HttpsConnectionFilterOptions httpsOptions = new HttpsConnectionFilterOptions();
                         httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = cert;
                         httpsOptions.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                         options.UseHttps(httpsOptions);
                     })
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseUrls($"https://localhost:{port}/")
                    .Build();
            host.Run();
```

**Startup file:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
            });
    }
```

**Error:**

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

**Made changes to "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"** 
added:

127.0.0.1 Test
localhost Test

to ensure, certificate name i.e.
"Test" same as the hostname.

**Error Stack Trace:**

2017-07-10T10:12:05.6963689-05:00  [ERR] ConnectionFilter.OnConnection (e77fccc9)
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__6.MoveNext()<---

2017-07-10T10:12:05.7203861-05:00  [ERR] ConnectionFilter.OnConnection (e77fccc9)
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__6.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.HttpsConnectionFilter.d__6.MoveNext()<---

Comment: Should I code server or expect the client certificate to be verified against those present in the local store(Trusted root certification authorities) by the framework?